# Is there a way to have a button render my camera component in React Native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am new to react native and am trying to make my camera component pop up whenever I click on a button. I am able to get the camera to render in App.js, but the minute I try to get it rendering in the component it just doesn't work. Should I use state to get this to render? If so, why doesn't react native allow you to just render a component within a component? I'm trying to understand the concept of components calling other components. Heres my code:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {Button, StyleSheet, Text, View} from 'react-native';
import DeviceCamera from './camera';

class CameraButton extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text> Button to Open Camera </Text>
        <Button
          onPress={() => {
            <DeviceCamera />;
          }}
          title="click me to open the camera!"
          color="#841584"
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#F5FCFF',
  },
  instructions: {
    textAlign: 'center',
    color: '#333333',
    marginBottom: 5,
  },
});

export default CameraButton;
```

I was trying to use the on press function to call the camera component but perhaps I am misunderstanding something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah, I would probably just use state here

```
class CameraButton extends Component {
  showCamera = () => this.setState({ showCamera: true });

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text> Button to Open Camera </Text>
        <Button
          onPress={this.showCamera}
          title="click me to open the camera!"
          color="#841584"
        />
        {this.state.showCamera && <DeviceCamera />}
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

With JSX, you can use `foo && <Bar />`; if foo evaluates to something truthy, then it will render your component, otherwise it will not.

Comment: okay! I think I understand most of that code. What exactly is that last line doing? It checks if both are true? But for what cause?

Comment: I tried implementing that line in my code and I got an error saying "null is not an object" (evaluating this.state.showCamera)

Comment: The link with the statement: this.state.showCamera. I added this state constructor: constructor(props){
  super(props);
  
  this.state = {
     showCamera: true,
  }
  }. but it opens the camera without the click of a button now

Comment: Oh yeah.  Sorry I haven't worked with classes in a while (upgrade to React with hooks, it's amazing).  And instantiate your state with `{ showCamera: false }`.

Comment: Ah, okay. That makes a lot of sense. I think I need to somehow turn my onpress into a function and update the value of state, is that right?

Comment: Exactly! Is the `showCamera` function I provided not working properly?  You may have to bind it to the correct context using `onPress={() => this.showCamera()}` or in your constructor `this.showCamera = this.showCamera.bind(this)`

Comment: I think it'll work fine if I just figure out how to change the state from false to true. right now the showCamera function just calls this.showCamera but it won't show because the state of show camera is false. do I make another function to set this to true? thank you for all your help so far

Comment: the `showCamera` function should be changing that state.  Put a `console.log(this.state)` inside that function and inside your render to make sure that function is being called and that the state is changing.